# IIS 7 setup with multiple sites

Tags: iis-7

There was a server in our office, which was used for intranet application. IIS 7 was setup and multiple sites were created using different port numbers. It was working fine without any issues.

Now this same machine has been converted to domain name like testweb.grp.com.
So now,I have setup the master site. And I have added the site1, site2, site3 mapped to their physical directories.. for example:

1. Master Site
   a.site1
   b.site2
   c.site3

   But now the problem is, when i browse these sites, it goes to the list of files rather than going to default(login) page. It lists all the files and folders.

I am using windows 2008 with iis 7.

Could you please help on this?.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are the sub folders applications or just virtual directories? To set as Applications right click the node and choose "Convert to Application".

Comment: If you enter address to the default page explicitly ie "http://mydomain/vitualdir/Default.aspx", does the page display correctly? It may be you don;t have a default documents set up correctly.

Comment: Thanks, I made a test page and tried browsing abc.com/virdir/default.htm. it works fine. now my question is why the applciation is not picking up the web.config when we invoke/start web application on the browser,

Comment: What sort of web applications is it - ASP.Net 2.0, webforms, ASP.Net 4.0 MVC - check to ensure that the default app pool runs ASP.Net 4.0 if your web apps require it, or create separate application pools for the virtual directories.

Comment: Application is ASP.Net 4.0 MVC, I have created separate pool for the master/parent directory.  For this pool, managed pipleline mode as 'Classic", and specified version 4.0,enabled-32bit application.

Comment: MVC need integrated pipeline normally or you can run into problems with routes etc. Why did you choose Classic?

Comment: Yes you are right, yesterday I changed my setting to "Integreated". Thanks very much